# A image carousel automatically appears while calling $content_bottom in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I am using $content_bottom in my home.tpl for displaying te latest products, but it displays default image carousel under it, which I want to remove.

I can't find where $content_bottom is declared in opencart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you already know its a `Carousel` you can go in admin interface to `Extension >> Modules >> Carousel` and remove it.

**P.S.** You really need to explore opencart and read the opencart Docs / forum . this question is not at all meant for stackoverflow